# Multiple Type Constraints in Swift

Tags: swift

Let's say I have these protocols:

```
protocol SomeProtocol {

}

protocol SomeOtherProtocol {

}
```

Now, if I want a function that takes a generic type, but that type must conform to `SomeProtocol` I could do:

```
func someFunc<T: SomeProtocol>(arg: T) {
    // do stuff
}
```

But is there a way to add a type constraint for multiple protocols?

```
func bothFunc<T: SomeProtocol | SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {

}
```

Similar things use commas, but in this case, it would start the declaration of a different type.  Here's what I've tried.

```
<T: SomeProtocol | SomeOtherProtocol>
<T: SomeProtocol , SomeOtherProtocol>
<T: SomeProtocol : SomeOtherProtocol>
```

Comment: This is a specially relevant question as the Swift docs don't mention this in the generics chapter...

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You can use a [where clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH37-XID_775) which lets you specify as many requirements as you want (all of which must be fulfilled) separated by commas

### Swift 2:

```
func someFunc<T where T:SomeProtocol, T:SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {
    // stuff
}
```

### Swift 3 & 4:

```
func someFunc<T: SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {
    // stuff
}
```

or the more powerful where clause:

```
func someFunc<T>(arg: T) where T:SomeProtocol, T:SomeOtherProtocol{
    // stuff
}
```

You can of course use protocol composition (e.g., `protocol<SomeProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol>` ), but it's a little less flexible.

Using `where` lets you deal with cases where multiple types are involved.

You may still want to compose protocols for reuse in multiple places, or just to give the composed protocol a meaningful name.

### Swift 5:

```
func someFunc(arg: SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol) { 
    // stuff
}
```

This feels more natural as the protocols are next to the argument.

Comment: Geez this isn't logical, but good to know I just want to be one of the thanks spammers for this one, havent' realised this in a month since I needed it.

Comment: Any way to do the same thing with classes and structs in the type contraint expression? e.g. `<T where T:SomeStruct, T:AnotherStruct>`? For classes the compiler appears to interpret this as saying "T is a subclass of both", and for structs it just complains that `"Type 'T' constrained to non-protocol type"`.

Comment: For the specific example in the OP:s question protocol composition _should_ be preferable method: the solution above is valid, but, imho, unnecessarily clutters the function signature. Also, using protocol composition as, e.g., a type constraint, still lets you use the `where` clause for additional type/other usage, e.g. `func someFunc<U, T: protocol<SomeProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol> where T.SubType == U>(arg: T, arg2: U) { ... }` for typealias `SubType` in e.g. `SomeProtocol`.

Comment: @dfri this is the answer to the question that was asked - I would probably use protocol composition in my code (though not in the function signature, I'd give it a name in most cases)

Comment: @Jiaaro I'd say this is _one_ answer to the question asked (the answer below shows another one). My comment were mostly related to the edit addition of the answer, namely _"Using `where` let's you deal with cases where there are multiple types involved"_, as this could possibly be interpreted (in this context)---by new Swift users reading this highly up-voted answer---as saying that you cannot combine the `where` versatility with protocol composition (which you naturally can: as shown in my comment above).

Comment: Looks like this is deprecated in swift3 and recommends to use: func someFunc<T>(arg: T) where T:SomeProtocol, T:SomeOtherProtocol {

Comment: Is there a way to tell swift that T needs to be of a certain object type AND implement a certain protocol?

Answer (score 74):

You have two possibilities:

1. You use a **[where clause](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/GenericParametersAndArguments.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH37-XID_775)** as indicated in Jiaaro's answer:

   ```
   func someFunc<T where T : SomeProtocol, T : SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {
       // do stuff
   }
   ```
2. You use a **[protocol composition type](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/swift_programming_language/Types.html#//apple_ref/swift/grammar/protocol-composition-type)**:

   ```
   func someFunc<T : protocol<SomeProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol>>(arg: T) {
       // do stuff
   }
   ```

Comment: imo the second solution is prettier, I'd go for this answer it is also more complete presenting two options

Comment: Number 2 is the only one that works for me under Swift 2 when declaring a `typealias`. Thanks!

Answer (score 19):

The evolution to Swift 3.0 brings some changes. Our two choices now look a little different.

**Using a `where` clause in Swift 3.0:**

The `where` clause has now moved to the end of a function signature to improve readability. So multiple protocol inheritance now looks like this:

```
func someFunc<T>(arg: T) where T:SomeProtocol, T:SomeOtherProtocol {

}
```

**Using the `protocol<>` construct in Swift 3.0:**

Composition using the `protocol<>` construct is being deprecated. The earlier `protocol<SomeProtocol, SomeOtherProtocol>` now looks like this:

```
func someFunc<T:SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {

}
```

**References.**

More info on the changes for `where` are here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0081-move-where-expression.md

And, more on the changes for the protocol<> construct are here: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0095-any-as-existential.md

Answer (score 19):

Swift 3 offers up to 3 different ways to declare your function.

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    /* ... */
}

protocol SomeOtherProtocol {
    /* ... */        
}
```

### 1. Using `&` operator

```
func someFunc<T: SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol>(arg: T) {
    /* ... */
}
```

### 2. Using `where` clause

```
func someFunc<T>(arg: T) where T: SomeProtocol, T: SomeOtherProtocol {
    /* ... */
}
```

### 3. Using `where` clause and `&` operator

```
func someFunc<T>(arg: T) where T: SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol {
    /* ... */        
}
```

---

Also note that you can use `typealias` in order to shorten your function declaration.

```
typealias RequiredProtocols = SomeProtocol & SomeOtherProtocol

func someFunc<T: RequiredProtocols>(arg: T) {
    /* ... */   
}
```