# Swift instance variable with protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, jsonmodel

I have to translate the following lines of Objective-c code into swift. This is a sample from the Objective-c [JSONModel-Framework](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel) where the `Optional` protocol provided by the Framework is applied to an instance variable of type `NSString`. I found a [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455327/how-do-i-specify-that-a-non-generic-swift-type-should-comply-to-a-protocol) but i didn't managed to achieve it. With my `MYModel.swift` implementation Xcode complains `Cannot specialize non-generic type NSString`

thx for your help!

**MYModel.swift**

```
@objc(MYModel) public class MYModel : JSONModel {
   ...
   public var name : NSString<Optional>
   ...
}
```

**MYModel.h**

```
@interface MYModel : JSONModel
...
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* name; 
...
```

**[JSONModel.h](https://github.com/icanzilb/JSONModel/blob/master/JSONModel/JSONModel/JSONModel.h)**

```
...
/**
 * Protocol for defining optional properties in a JSON Model class. Use like below to define 
 * model properties that are not required to have values in the JSON input:
 * 
 * @property (strong, nonatomic) NSString<Optional>* propertyName;
 *
 */
@protocol Optional
@end
...
```

Comment: What's the problem you're encountering in translating it?

Comment: @Antonio: Updated description

Comment: You'll probably have problems with that. Swift already has optionals at language level, and non-optional variables must always be initialized during instantiation. But besides that, I presume that the JSON framework you're using use reflection/introspection to populate instances, and that won't work in swift

Comment: Thx Antonio. The JSONModel framework is actually working with swift, as long as u use Objective-c types for your swift classes instance variables and annotate the class with @objc(MYModel)

Comment: Yeah that's right, but making objc compatible automatically means you cannot use swift specific features - such as generics. As long as you are ok with that...

Comment: As i couldn't find another framework which is doing proper object-graph-mapping from/to json within swift i'm fine with that. At least for now... :)

Comment: FYI, I found [this blog post](http://robots.thoughtbot.com/efficient-json-in-swift-with-functional-concepts-and-generics) inspiring - pure swift, a little complex to understand at first. I have used it to develop my own framework, which works fine (unfortunately closed source atm, maybe in a near future I'll be allowed to open it)

Answer (score 1):

The `<` and `>` are not for *conforms to protocol*. It is for Types with generics like Array:

```
Array<T>
```

so you can write `var a: Array<String>`.

You want something else, a variable should be a Type `String` **and** conform to the protocol

---

You can extend String with the protocol and add the needed functions yourself.

Since your `Optional` protocol is empty, it is enough to write:

```
extension NSString: Optional {} // you can use String if you like
```

To create the protocol write in Swift:

```
protocol Optional {}
```

You can Objective-C create the protocol, too.

---

You should not use Optional, because there is already one, but because Swift has namespacing, it works.
You could of course write something like that:

```
extension NSString: JsonOptProtocol {}

protocol JsonOptProtocol {} // or create that in Objective-C like you did
```

---

[Documentation link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-XID_403)

Comment: Thx for your answer! That is actually what i'm looking for. If i try your example `extension NSString: Optional{}` Xcode complains that `Reference to generic type Optional requires arguments in <...>`

Comment: Haha, oh that is funny, you should not use Optional, because there is already one in the docs. You have to create the protocol of course, added to answer.

Comment: It works with Optional, because it knows you are using your self created protocol named `Optional`. But you could also use another name for your protocol of course.

Answer (score 0):

Optional is a type declared in the standard library of Swift, at the moment JSONModel is not compatible with Swift because of this.

Comment: I see. As a workaround i can overwrite JSONModel's `propertyIsOptional` method to set all parameters "optional" (which is fine for me) as well as the `validate` method to handle possible validation there.

Comment: yes, I guess a quick fix will be to remove the Optional protocol from JSONModel files, and then just use propertyIsOptional in your models