# Protocols and associated types in arrays

Tags: swift, generics, protocols, swift-protocols

I have a protocol `Node`:

```
protocol Node {
   var parent: Node?
   var children: [Node]
}
```

which is implemented by classes:

```
class TreeNode: Node {
   var parent: Node?
   var children: [Node]
}
```

But this poses a problem as accessing the parent in `TreeNode` now gives me a `Node`, and I want to do `TreeNode` specific operations on them. So I want to change the protocol to:

```
protocol Node {
   associatedtype T: Node

   var parent: T?
   var children: [T]
}
```

Which let's me define the class as:

```
class TreeNode: Node {
   var parent: TreeNode?
   var children: [TreeNode]
}
```

Great! But there's a catch. If I want to write a helper method for `Node` that deals with arrays:

```
func getReversedChildren<T: Node>(node: T) -> [T] {
   return node.children.reversed()
}
```

The compiler fails with the error:
`Cannot convert return expression of type 'ReversedCollection<[T.T]>' to return type '[T]'`

From what I can gather about this issue, I need to achieve a type-erasure mechanism to support this architecture. But how can this be done on my example?

Comment: How is ArcNode defined ?

Comment: @claude31 Typo, should be `Node`. Updated question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want the parent and children of a node to be of the *same type* as the node itself, not just *some* type conforming to `Node`. That would be `Self` in the protocol definition:

```
protocol Node {
    var parent: Self? { get set }
    var children: [Self] { get set }
}
```

Now you can define the concrete class (see [A Swift protocol requirement that can only be satisfied by using a final class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37141067/a-swift-protocol-requirement-that-can-only-be-satisfied-by-using-a-final-class) for why the class needs to be `final`):

```
final class TreeNode: Node {
    var parent: TreeNode? = nil
    var children: [TreeNode] = []
}
```

and

```
func getReversedChildren<T: Node>(node: T) -> [T] {
    return node.children.reversed()
}
```

compiles without problems.

Comment: This is it! Thank you :)