# Protocol conformance fails in non-final class because it uses 'Self' as a non-parameter, non-result type

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols

I'm working on a method I can use to only update a property with a new value if the new value is different from the current. I have come up with a protocol for this. However, I am getting compiler errors:

Here are a few sample models:

```
class Model {
    var id: Int = 0
}

class Person: Model {
    var name: String = ""
}

class Dog: Model {
    var color: UIColor = .black
}
```

Here is the protocol:

```
protocol Updatable: AnyObject{

    @discardableResult
    func update<Value: Equatable>(
        _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, Value>,
        to value: Value
    ) -> Bool
}
```

And here is a default implementation:

```
extension Updatable {
    @discardableResult
    func update<Value: Equatable>(
        _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, Value>,
        to value: Value
    ) -> Bool {
        guard self[keyPath: keyPath] != value else { return false }
        self[keyPath: keyPath] = value
        return true
    }
}
```

Now I would like for all of my Model subclasses to inherit this update feature:

```
extension Model: Updatable {}
```

However, I get a compiler error:

> Protocol 'Updatable' requirement 'update(_:to:)' cannot be satisfied by a non-final class ('Model') because it uses 'Self' in a non-parameter, non-result type position

Now I understand why this would be a problem due to inheritance. The Self constraint would be different for each Model subclass and overriding would be impossible.

What gets me is that I can work around this issue by defining a blank protocol and adding a default protocol method with the same signature to an extension:

```
protocol Updatable2: AnyObject { }

extension Updatable2 {

    @discardableResult
    func update2<Value: Equatable>(
        _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Self, Value>,
        to value: Value
    ) -> Bool {
        print("Default: \(keyPath) -> \(value)")
        guard self[keyPath: keyPath] != value else { return false }
        self[keyPath: keyPath] = value
        return true
    }
}


extension Model: Updatable2 {}
```

The compiler gives me no trouble at all. All of the following are valid:

```
let model = Model()
model.update2(\.id, to: 200)

let person = Person()
person.update2(\.name, to: "Sally")
person.update2(\.id, to: 400)

let car = Car()
car.update2(\.wheels, to: 5)

let models: [Model] = [
    model,
    person,
    car,
]
models.forEach { $0.update2(\.id, to: 666) }
```

How is this possible?

Comment: Just to be clear, does your workaround involve deleting the old `Updatable`?

Comment: Oh, I should have made that clear. I have no need for both protocols. So yeah, only one protocol would exist.

Comment: I think the real issue here is that you, @RobC, have not been able to shake the inner _intuitive_ conviction that `MyType<Model>` and `MyType<Person>` should be somehow related just because Person descends from Model. But of course this is not true; as you know with your _rational_ brain, they are completely independent types. There is no polymorphism here, no inheritance. Well, the same for `MyType<Self>`. Self here is not polymorphic. It does not mean "Me and my descendants". It just means Me.

Answer (score 2):

> Now I understand why this would be a problem due to inheritance. The Self constraint would be different for each `Model` subclass and overriding would be impossible.

Overriding is not the reason. The reason, as explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37141531/5133585), is that the inherited method does not implement the protocol anymore.

```
class ModelSubclass: Model {
    /*
     inherits
     func update<Value: Equatable>(
         _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Model, Value>,
         to value: Value
     ) -> Bool {
     
     but should have
     func update<Value: Equatable>(
         _ keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<ModelSubclass, Value>,
         to value: Value
     ) -> Bool {
     */
}
```

Naturally, removing the requirement works, because this whole thing is caused by the protocol *requiring* `ModelSubclass` to have a certain method.

Now, I know what you're going to say: "But I have a default implementation, so every implementation should have all the `update` methods it needs!" Well, logically I think you are correct, but the Swift compiler doesn't bother checking for things like that. [This](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/182946e6be9b081bc2f2e72dd915c925f41ed190/lib/Sema/TypeCheckProtocol.cpp#L4064) is the line of code in the compiler where it emits the error message. As you can see, before that, it only checks if the protocol has `Self` in an invariant position (the `final` check is done before calling the enclosing method):

```
if (selfRefInfo.selfRef == TypePosition::Invariant) {
  // References to Self in a position where subclasses cannot do
  // the right thing. Complain if the adoptee is a non-final
  // class.
```

Side note:

If `Self` is the parameter type (contravariant) or return type (covariant), then it's fine. Consider:

```
protocol Foo {
    func f(x: Self)
    func g() -> Self
}

class Bar: Foo {
    func f(x: Bar) { }
    
    // note that the covariant Self return type is required here
    // you cannot use Bar here
    func g() -> Self {
        fatalError()
    }
}

class BarSubclass: Bar {
    /*
     inherits:
     func f(x: Bar)
     
     which can take any BarSubclass as parameter, so it can satisfy
     func f(x: BarSubclass)
     
     also inherits:
     func g() -> Self
     
     which is the same as what it should implement :)
     */
}
```